# Max value in a for loop python

Tags: python, for-loop, max

I've been trying to figure out how to print the maximum value from a for loop. It's required for my homework assignment. I've tried using the max function but I keep getting

`TypeError: unorderable types: str() > float()`.

```
for NP in range(MP, MaxP+1, 10):

        CostofTicket = TP - (((NP - MP)/10)*.5)
        Gross = NP * CostofTicket
        Profit = (NP * CostofTicket) - FixedCost

        print (NP, end="          ")
        print ("$", format(CostofTicket, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
        print ("$", format(Gross, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
        print ("$", format(FixedCost, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
        print ("$", format(Profit, "3,.2f"))



    print ("Maximum Profit: ", end="")
    print (max(Profit, "3,.2f"))
    print ("Maximum Profit Ticket Price: ")
    print ("Maximum Profit Number of Passengers: ")
```

Comment: What's intended by "`(max(Profit, "3,.2f"))`"?  Are you trying to take the greatest value that `Profit` held during the `for` loop?  If so, you should accumulate `Profit` into (e.g.) `profits` like so: `profits.append(Profit)`.

Comment: `help(max)` will tell you how to use the function.

Comment: It helps to post the full traceback in the question and to boil the problem down to a simple demonstration that we can run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max` is indeed what you want.  The `TypeError` you get is because you're treating it like your calls to `format()`.  Instead, separate these steps and give the result to `max` a name for convenience.

```
profits = []
for NP in range(MP, MaxP+1, 10):

        CostofTicket = TP - (((NP - MP)/10)*.5)
        Gross = NP * CostofTicket
        Profit = (NP * CostofTicket) - FixedCost
        profits.append(Profit)

    # ... print()s ...    


    greatest_profit = max(profits)
    print ("Maximum Profit: ", end="")
    print (format(greatest_profit, "3,.2f"))
    print ("Maximum Profit Ticket Price: ")
    print ("Maximum Profit Number of Passengers: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to spend memory with a list, simply save the maximun in a variable and put it in contest against the produced values in each iteration.

```
maxProfit = float("-inf") # First contendant is -Infinity, a real low number

for NP in range(MP, MaxP+1, 10):
    CostofTicket = TP - (((NP - MP)/10)*.5)
    Gross = NP * CostofTicket
    Profit = (NP * CostofTicket) - FixedCost
    if Profit > maxProfit: # Here is the Fight. Winner stays with the trophy "maxProfit"
        maxProfit = Profit
    print (NP, end="          ")
    print ("$", format(CostofTicket, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(Gross, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(FixedCost, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(Profit, "3,.2f"))

print ("Maximum Profit: ", end="")
print (format(maxProfit, "3,.2f")) # And the winer is...
print ("Maximum Profit Ticket Price: ")
print ("Maximum Profit Number of Passengers: ")
```

This code doesn't use memory (a list) and gives you intuition about how the mentioned `max` function is implemented.

You could also avoid using memory with a generator:

```
import operator

def ticket_values(MP, MaxP, TP, FixedCost):
    for NP in range(MP, MaxP+1, 10):
        CostofTicket = TP - (((NP - MP)/10)*.5)
        Gross = NP * CostofTicket
        Profit = (NP * CostofTicket) - FixedCost
        yield (NP, CostofTicket, Gross, Profit)

for ticket_value in ticket_values(MP, MaxP, TP, FixedCost):
    print (ticket_value[0], end="          ")
    print ("$", format(ticket_value[1], "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(ticket_value[2], "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(FixedCost, "3,.2f"), end="          ")
    print ("$", format(ticket_value[3], "3,.2f"))

print ("Maximum Profit: ", end="")
print (format(max(ticket_values(MP, MaxP, TP, FixedCost), key=operator.itemgetter(3))[3], "3,.2f"))
print ("Maximum Profit Ticket Price: ")
print ("Maximum Profit Number of Passengers: ")
```

You'll get the idea.

Comment: why use ``lambda`` when there is a perfectly acceptable builtin: ``operator.itemgetter(3)``?

Comment: Why not? `lambda` is also a native Python feature. In fact, you don't need to `import` anything to use it.

Comment: because it's faster and a bit easier to understand and even though you need to `import` it it's a builtin.

Comment: Aw. Those are different reasons than the mere existence of an builtin alternative: _Faster_ and _Understandable_. I accept _faster_, but _understandable_ is subjective. How much faster? I don't think we are talking about orders of magnitude, do we?.

Comment: A factor 2-3 faster at least in my testings.

Comment: Good to take that in account.

When there is a bottle neck in that point of the code, I will change it ;-)

Just kidding. Thank you for the info. Changed!